# How can I best correct / handle a slight right skew distribution in my residuals plot using stats.models mixed effects model?

Tags: mixed-model, python, data-transformation, statsmodels, skew-normal-distribution

I am using `statsmodels` `mixedlm` as follows:

```
model = smf.mixedlm("value ~ categorical_variable", data, groups=data[year_id])
```

When plotting my residuals I get a distribution that looks like below:[image]

It's *very* close to normal but there's a slight shift to the right. And in the Q-Q plot there is deviation at the tails.

I've explored various transformations, including potentially using a `skew.normal` distribution but I am not sure how to implement that transformation (I am very new to modeling).

Does anyone have any recommendations for handling data with a slight right skew?

Comment: What are you trying to find out?  Why do you need a mixed model?  (I don't know Python, but I am guessing that the groups = has something to do with the random effect).

Comment: @PeterFlom hello! I am trying to determine the impact of `categorical_variable` on `value` using the group value to factor in potential variability from `field` and `id`.

Comment: The slight skew probably is immaterial, but can you plese tell us in practical language, what is the goal?